# Migrating one shop from Magento multistore install

Tags: magento, transfer, migrating

I need to export/migrate one shop from a Magento multistore install. Googled it but haven't found a quick solution to migrate only one shop. Is there anybody with any advice here on how to do it?

Comment: Why not migrate both and just remove the one you dont want..

Comment: Because that webshop is sold and the others are still mine.

Comment: You could just make a local copy of your stores, and then delete the stores you want taken out. you can then setup the store on a live server again with the only store you want.

Comment: @GershonHerczeg or Andrew should post their answer as, you know, an answer so that Hidde can officially accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this on my localhost: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server, removed the other shop and clients and made another (new) backup of this. This seems the best solution so far.

(Thanks @Andrew for suggesting this)